# Set a rule to import text data as pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have the following .txt file:

```
945       21/01/2019                   -12,47       TRANSACTION 1        10,97000 IN  GBP  1,13674 %   

945       21/01/2019                   -14,47       TRANSACTION 2        10,97000 IN  GBP  1,13674 %   

(...)
```

And I would like to import it in Python as **Pandas Dataframe**, in which:

each row is a transaction, and a column is defined **if there are more than 2 whitespaces** between characters;

```
print(final_df)
Col_1      Col_2                        Col_3           Col_4               Col_5           Col_6
945       21/01/2019                   -12,47       TRANSACTION 1        10,97000 IN  GBP  1,13674 %
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try of using space `\s+` as seperator

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\1124612\Desktop\text.txt',sep='\s+',header = None)
df
```

Out:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   945 21/01/2019  -12,47  TRANSACTION 1   10,97000    IN  GBP 1,13674 %
1   945 21/01/2019  -14,47  TRANSACTION 2   10,97000    IN  GBP 1,13674 %
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is very good at data processing, not for decoding data as poorly formatted as what you have shown (more that one space as delimiter, every second line empty).

A bullet proof way would be to filter input, and use the csv module to parse the result, because it accept an iterator as input (while `pd.read_csv` do not).

So this should do the job:

```
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd

def filter(fd):
    """Cleaning filter.

Will replace sequences of more that one space with a single tab, to process the
file as as tsv, and filter out empty lines
"""
    rx = re.compile('\s\s+')      # the pretended delimiter
    for line in fd:
        line = line.strip()       # clean out end of line
        if len(line) == 0:      
            continue              # filter out empty lines
        yield rx.sub('\t', line)  # and return non empty lines properly delimited

df = pd.DataFrame(list(csv.reader(filter(open('infile.txt'), delimiter='\t')))
print(df)
```

will output:

```
     0           1       2    ...                4    5          6
0  945  21/01/2019  -12,47    ...      10,97000 IN  GBP  1,13674 %
1  945  21/01/2019  -14,47    ...      10,97000 IN  GBP  1,13674 %

[2 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: It works, but correct the parentesis as: df = pd.DataFrame(list(csv.reader(filter_1(open(path)), delimiter='\t')));  furthermore, I renamed the function filter_1 to avoid clashes.